# Get frame object that function was defined in

Tags: python, introspection

Is there any way to programmatically find the frame that a function was defined in? I'm looking for something like a function `get_defining_frame` that would work like this:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        pass
    return bar

bar = foo()

get_defining_frame(foo) # should be the same as inspect.currentframe()
get_defining_frame(bar) # should be the frame created by the call to foo
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames are created/deleted on every function call. So when you call:

```
get_defining_frame(bar)
```

in your example code, the frame where `bar` was created is already gone.

Function objects don't hold a reference to the frame they were defined in. It's a good thing because it would keep all other local variables from being freed.

Why do you need this?

Comment: We're trying to visualize of code as it runs. I'm fairly certain that that frame should still be accessible, though... if there were a variable `x` in `foo`, then calling `bar` after the fact should still have access to `x`, right?

Comment: To `x`, yes, but not to the frame that also referred to `x`. When a local variable is referenced from a nested function, it actually becomes a cell variable. There's an extra layer of indirection compared to normal local variables, precisely so the frame object doesn't have to stick around. The cell variables are kept alive (individually), everything else about the frame object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this sort of information unless you store it yourself (a decorator perhaps).
Have a look at `bar.__code__` and `bar.__closure__`, maybe they provide you with enough info.
`__closure__` will not store the entire context for when bar was created, only the variables referenced by bar for memory-efficiency reasons.

A decorator that should do the trick:

```
def save_frame(func):
    frame=inspect.currentframe().f_back
    func.__frame = frame
    return func
```

Bear in mind that using this will really mess up garbage collection, storing the entire stack frame means nothing referenced anywhere in the stack can be GC-ed (that's why `__closure__` only captures what is referenced).

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from an answer I posted on a different topic, but found it very applicable to the question. It goes up the frames to locate the one where the function is defined, or should have been defined in.

The code below was designed to find out if a function has already been defined in a class, module, or in `__main__`. Before it returns what it finds, it has found the locals dictionary of the object in which the function is declared. So it could be modified to return the locals dict or frame.

The problem this addressed was how to find the scope for a function during class declaration before the function was bound to the class. So `o.__self__` or other properties weren't yet assigned. This was part of an implementation for a decorator.

This works on Python 3, but not 2.

```
>>> def _find_scope(func):
...     try:
...         owner_qname = '.'.join(func.__qualname__.split('.')[:-1])
...         if len(owner_qname) == 0:
...             module = sys.modules['__main__']
...             if hasattr(module, func.__name__):
...                 return module.__dict__
...             else:
...                 return None
...         i = 0
...         while True:
...             f_locals = sys._getframe(i).f_locals
...             i += 1
...             if ('__qualname__' in f_locals and
...                 f_locals['__qualname__'] == owner_qname):
...                     if func.__name__ in f_locals:
...                         return f_locals
...                     else:
...                         return None
...     except ValueError:
...         return None
```